# How can I schedule a job for a PHP script stored on our FTP server without using third parties like Cpanel etc?

Tags: php

I have a script that triggers an email to be sent with a CSV attachment. I want this to be automated for specific times, It needs to be so it can run at night when I am not active on my PC. I would rather not use third party sites to trigger these jobs. Microsoft Azure or our Ubuntu server could be options if possible.

Comment: There is typically software on the server that does this. Talk to the server admin. On Linux/Unix, the tool is called `cron`. (This is too broad a question for Stack Overflow in its current form, though, I'm afraid.)

Comment: Sorry this is my first day on Stack Overflow, what would you mean by too broad of a question? Do questions need to be extremely case specific?

Comment: Yeah, specific programming questions (but not so specific the answers won't be of use to anyone else) with some (not too much) code really tend to work best. And if they're broad, then at least they'll need some detail people can work with - in this case, what OS the server is running e.g. (but then you'll probably already find your answer by Googling `<name of OS> schedule job`).  What is on topic here and what isn't can be a bit arcane at times - but you'll get the hang of it. The basic ethos is to build a library of questions & answers useful for future readers.

Comment: @Pekka웃 can you explain why a flag for too broad got disputed?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint not really, no! That looks like the right choice....

Comment: @Pekka웃 clearly 3 other people thought so too